# Drop all rows if there is at least one specific value in column

Tags: python, dataframe, if-statement, conditional-statements

I am trying to write a code in Python to drop all observations of a certain `id` if there is at least one specific value in the column `worked`. Think of it as if you want to know which employee was never absent during the year, so he/she will get a bonus for showing up every single day. Then, it is the same if someone was absent 1 or 50 days, because that person does not have perfect presentism that year.

Let's say the df looks like this (df):

```
  id worked
1 A  yes
2 A  no
3 B  yes
4 B  yes
5 C  no
6 C  no
7 D  yes
8 D  yes
```

The ideal new df should look like this (df2):

```
  id worked
3 B  yes
4 B  yes
7 D  yes
8 D  yes
```

```
df2 = df1[df1.worked == 'yes']
```

doesn't do the job because it will remove `id` C but it will still show 1 line of `id` A who did not show up at least 1 day.

I want to make sure that if I do

```
df2.id.unique()
```

only B and D get a bonus, instead of A, B and D.

Just to make it clear, I need to get df2 and not the list of `unique()`. That was just to make an example of the possible uses of df2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example. I need to add an auxiliary column however:

```
df['aux_col'] = df.groupby('id')['worked'].transform('nunique')
final_df = df[(df['aux_col'] == 1) & (df['worked'] == 'yes')]
final_df = final_df.drop(columns='aux_col')
print(final_df)
```

Output:

```
  id worked
2  B    yes
3  B    yes
6  D    yes
7  D    yes
```

Double checking as you stated:

```
print(final_df['id'].unique())
```

Returns:

```
['B' 'D']
```

Comment: Perfect! It does the job. But how do I get rid of the message ```A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame``` that comes with the first line of code?

Comment: I am not getting it, are you sure you aren't doing something different before?

Comment: Probably that's the problem. I will update if I find what it is

Answer (score 1):

You may try [`df.duplicated`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html):

```
>>> df2 = df1[df1.duplicated(keep=False)]
>>> df2[df2.worked == 'yes']
  id worked
3  B    yes
4  B    yes
7  D    yes
8  D    yes
```

Or use a logical and (`&`):

```
>>> f1[df1.duplicated(keep=False) & (df1.worked == 'yes')]
  id worked
3  B    yes
4  B    yes
7  D    yes
8  D    yes
```

Comment: I think that would not work if I have 1 more observation for each ```id```. For example, if I add 1 day in which everyone showed up, I will end with a df that has at least one observation for each employee